# Why I cannot use @action decorator on ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, decorator

I build a very basic **ViewSet** on `User` model to CRUD a user.

- I want to use `ModelViewSet` and `@action` decorator to make codes clean.
- Set a permission(Just use `IsAuthenticated` as example) required on the `list` function. so that only who are signed can do this.

This is the code sample.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action, list_route
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I got an error

> Cannot use the @action decorator on the following methods, as they are existing routes: list

If I remove `@action`, it works well. My question is why I cannot use @action decorator on an existing routes `list`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@action` is for "extra actions" which actually means (if you inspect the code): "not explicityly defined in the router". So if you are registering your view in urls using `DefaultRouter` or `SimpleRouter`, then router will throw this error.

For your case you can modify `View.get_permissions` as shown in [docs example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions):

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return [IsAuthenticated()]
        else:
            return super(self, UserViewSet).get_permissions()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just a little bit moderation, it should be `return [IsAuthenticated()]`, or it will except [has_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097910/has-permission-missing-1-required-positional-argument-view)

Answer (score 3):

Even if it doesn't answer the specific question of this user, I'm gonna post for anyone arriving here after the misleading title, you **can** use @action decorators for a `ModelViewSet`

Define the viewset as following:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='my-action')
    def my_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Get last property-run and return associated results """
        instance = self.get_object()
        # custom code
        custom_response = {"test": "hello world"}
        return Response(custom_response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Define the router and apis

```
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import url

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'mymodel', MyModelViewSet)
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api/1/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Then simply access it via `api/1/mymodel/1/my-action`

Comment: Is @action only applicable to ModelViewSet?

Answer (score -1):

#### You have not imported action

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
```

See the examples on [drf documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)